# initAutocomplete is not a function (works in local machine but shows issue when it's deployed in live server)

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am trying to use google map api.
it works perfectly in local machine. but when I deploy the code in live server, it shows error in console, and I am not able to load google map

**Script :**

```
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
    async defer></script>

    function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center : {
            lat : 11.39930615709189,
            lng : 79.69353675842285
        },
        zoom : 13,
        mapTypeId : 'roadmap'
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    document.getElementById('addAddress').addEventListener('click',
            function() {
                addAddress(geocoder, map, service);
            });

    var markers = [];
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
        var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

        if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Clear out the old markers.
        markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        });
        markers = [];

        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
            }
            var icon = {
                url : place.icon,
                size : new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin : new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor : new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize : new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                icon : icon,
                title : place.name,
                position : place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                // Only geocodes have viewport.
                bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    /* document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    }); */

    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService;

}
```

**Error :**

> Uncaught (in promise)     Xc    message : "initAutocomplete is not a
>   function"       name: "InvalideValueError"      stack: "Error
>       at new Xc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:63:227)
>       at Object._.Yc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:63:337)
>       at Uh (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:132:221)
>       at https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete:132:107"

Comment: Is the function's code in an external js file? Where do you call the function from? Make sure you load the file before using the function

Comment: both the script of function and file is there with body tag.

<script
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAN8ZheE-fA3h7fXjWnAhkmTLpF8_iq9I8&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
 async defer></script>

<script>
function initAutocomplete() {
......
}
</script>                                                                                                                                                             Do I need to change the structure?

Comment: Have you tried to remove the async option in the script tag?

Comment: I just followed opposite of your first comment. I loaded the function before loading the google script. Now it works fine. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.
I loaded the maps script after defining the functions.
And now it works fine.